# Eclipse with tomcat : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when I try running a web service client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat7, axis

I am developing a SOAP web service with **Axis2/Eclipse/Tomcat** and I'm hitting `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` when I try running the web service client.

I have two projects on Eclipse: **MyWebService**, which contains the actual source code and from where I generate the wsdl; and **MyWebServiceClient**, which contains the proxy, service locator, soap binding stub, etc. (generated automatically by Eclipse)

The java methods that are later exposed as SOAP methods work normally when they're run as a Java application.

I changed the code a few times and replaced the method bodies with dummy contents (e.g., return 1 or return true straight away, without any logic processing). The stubs have worked perfectly.

In this sense one thing I noticed is that the problem only happens when I instantiate a class from "MyWebService" project on my JSP file (which sits on the Client project). And this led me to another thought: where are the references to "MyWebService" classes in the "MyWebServiceClient"? (I couldn't find any...)

The client was generated automatically, so I believe I am missing something here... If the references to the WS are missing, what would be the correct way to add them into MyWebServiceClient?

Thanks

-EDIT-
Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at net.phil.hello.HelloSoapBindingStub.poll(HelloSoapBindingStub.java:149)
    at net.phil.hello.HelloProxy.poll(HelloProxy.java:56)
    at org.apache.jsp.aa_jsp._jspService(aa_jsp.java:72)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1121)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:614)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:777)
```

Comment: Share complete exception, it shall contain relevant information. Search serverside tomcat logs as well.

Comment: One more thing I noticed: it only fails when I use HIBERNATE

Comment: Please check [this link](http://sansatechnology.wordpress.com/2010/02/06/apache-axis2-codegen-plugin-error-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception/) if you used CodeGen plugin. I think the axis has problem with your message. Please check declaration of WSDL and XSD targetnamespace or share your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hibernate JARs hadn't been included to the web project (WEB-INF/lib), only to the Eclipse project

Thanks Leos.